# Eclipse editor not showing error markers

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

My eclipse is not showing error in its file editor. I have tried cleaning and putting project on Build Automatically. However when I run it then I do see the compiler error in console and also in problem view just after saving the file. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this ?

[image: Eclipse Screenshot after saving changes: line 43]

This is the version of my eclipse:

> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)

Adding more images:
[image]

[image]

Comment: clean the project..

Comment: did that many times.

Comment: Eclipse Neon must be run using Java 8

Comment: Check if the file editor is a Java editor and not a resource editor.  Open the file with Ctrl + Shift + T and it will get the correct editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Build Path of the project by right clicking the project and select Build Path -> Configure Build Path.

JDK is not properly configure for project. Configure your JDK instead of in-build JRE.

Also make sure your source folder is also configure in Build Path (for example MyProject/src) must listed as a Source folder.

In Java Compiler-->Errors/warning, click Restore Default.

Make sure "Build Automatically" is checked.

Comment: I think I have those path right but its still the same. See updated question. I have added more images to it.

Comment: Take following step
1. Clean Project
2. Check "Build Automatically"
3. Inside Java Compilers--> Errors/ Warning, click Restore Default.

Comment: Following Similar Steps for Scala Compiler worked for me. However, it was initially default, I check in use Project Settings, and it worked for me.